# HLSL code not registering?

Tags: c++, hlsl, directx-9

I'm going to ask a relatively general question.

I'm using VC++ 2010, programming a Direct X9 application with a shader component. The program compiles fine, it draws a lighted and textured square. The problem is that although the c++ end of the program works fine and alterations such as changing the lighting colours or texture positions work fine all alterations to the .fx file are ignored. In fact removing the file from the specified directory actually has no effect on the program.

Is this a compiler problem? Surely the HLSL file is not useless, I mean I'm passing variables to it so where could they be going?

main.cpp: mediafire.com/?9n4llrclcfohqfb

transform.fx: mediafire.com/?jqach463p2vcqhz

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to answer this without more details, such as: How are you loading your shader? Are you sure it isn't loading a copy in the same directory as the executable? Are the changes you talk about something that happen *while* the program is running, or *between* running different instances of the program?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?9n4llrclcfohqfb
http://www.mediafire.com/?jqach463p2vcqhz
main.cpp and transform.fx;
between diferent instances, I change the code, recompile and the changes are evident;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this is actually quite shameful, it turns out that I forgot to edit the directory of the .fx file in the D3DXCreateEffectFromFile function so the file I was editing of course had no impact on the application. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Shaders do not recompile on the fly, so if you modify the shader code while your program is running you need to call D3DXCreateEffectFromFile again to create a new compiled instance of your shader.

Comment: I'm not that new. I close the program before changing the code and run the newly compiled executable.

Comment: So if you remove the fx file, recompile and rerun it still runs?

Comment: Also maybe in Debug check what's in ID3DXBuffer* errors. Also on your cpp code mhTech = mFX->GetTechniqueByName("AmbientDiffuseSpecTech"); is commented but you still call mFX->SetTechnique(mhTech); . And on your shader file line 83 : float3 texColor = 0xfffffffftex2D(TexS, tex0).rgb; will make sure the shader doesn't compile

Comment: errors is clean, GetTechnique works no matter what I put into it or if I comment it out, but I still need to call SetTechnique and as I said before, nothing I do to the shader seems to alter the program.
I can completely erase the file and the square is still drawn.

Comment: I loaded your shader in d3d engine (vvvv),it compiles and any modifications work out of the box, so it's definitely something in your c++ code. I'll build your code and let you know.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried wiping all existing debug files to see if it's some sort of cache problem but it doesn't seem to help.